# importing excel data with Python

Tags: python, excel, xls

I'm trying to create a feature class from XY table using excel data .xls

I just found out MakeXYEventLayer_management however it seems it doesn't apply to .xls.
do I have to change my ~100 files into csv, or someone knows a trick?

Cheers

Comment: What is a  `MakeXYEventLayer_management`? What is it purpose?: Is it in Python or execel, and where does it come from?

Answer (score 3):

[xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) should work for you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is it to replace MakeXYEventLayer_management?

Comment: No - it s a library that shoulda llow you to read form .xls files into Python data structures